# Extension to constrained Dictionary Conforming to Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, extension-methods

I am trying to create a protocol that allows any object to be instantiated using JSON NSData.

I am trying to create an extension to [String: String] dictionary that conforms to this protocol. Unfortunately for some reason the following code doesn't work:

```
public protocol InitializableWithData {
    init(data: NSData?) throws 
}


extension Dictionary: InitializableWithData where Key: String, Value: String {
    public init(data: NSData?) {
        self.init()
        // Parse NSData into a [String: String]
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Extension of type 'Dictionary' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
```

I have also tried with:

```
extension Dictionary: InitializableWithData where Key: NSString, Value: NSString {
    public init(data: NSData?) {
        self.init()
        // Parse NSData into a [String: String]
    }
}
```

Given that String is a struct, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I can remember you cannot conditionally create an extension conforming to a protocol based on some generic constraints :/