# Protocol Extension of Constrained Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, swift-protocols, swift-dictionary

I'm trying to get a specific Dictionary type to conform to a protocol.

```
typealias FirebaseDictionary = Dictionary<String, FirebaseValue>
```

I would like to have the conform to a `FirebaseValue` protocol

```
protocol FirebaseValue {
    // stuff here
}
```

I tried this

```
extension FirebaseDictionary: FirebaseValue {

}
```

but I got an error `Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Dictionary' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause`. So I now have this

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == FirebaseValue {

}
```

but I cannot figure out the proper syntax to make this conform to a protocol, if at all possible. If not possible is there any other way to achieve the same effect? I'm trying to only allow specific types into a property, and be able to discern easily what type they are when read back.

[This question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950561/extension-to-constrained-dictionary-conforming-to-protocol) but was given no definitive answer, and it may have changed regardless

Comment: Swift doesn't have [conditional conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) yet – workarounds would either be a wrapper type that contains a `[String: FirebaseValue]` and provides the conformance to `FirebaseValue` (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/33332613/2976878), or if possible, just define additional overloads of the (presumed) functions that you were planning on using with `FirebaseValue` to work with `[String: FirebaseValue]` as well.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you. I tried as in the link but I cannot get `struct FirebaseDictionary<String, FirebaseValue>` to conform the protocol `FirebaseValue` even when empty. I get `Inheritance from non-protocol type 'FirebaseValue'`

Comment: I figured it out, i had improper syntax

Comment: @JustinOroz Post the results please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Swift 4.2 you can do this with:

```
extension Dictionary : FirebaseValue where Key == String, Value == FirebaseValue {
}
```